# Network Boot Worker Node

Tags: network-boot

**Project:** [How to build a Raspbery Pi Cluster][1]

**Summarize the problem.** Worker Node will not fully boot.
ERROR: **[   32.474616] cam-dummy-reg: disabling**

**Provide details and any research:**
(Performed on master and worker-node1)
latest eeprom-boot-loader firmware via command-line;

```
sudo apt install rpi-eeprom
sudo rpi-eeprom-update -d -a
```

Tried restarting services NFS, RPCbind, dhcp,and TFTP

re-imaged OS on master 1 time and on worker 2 times.

Worker Node;

```
sudo apt update and upgrade-full
sudo apt install firmware-brcm80211 --fix-broken
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
sudo rpi-update
```

**Thoughts**
Maybe should have chosen 64bit OS instead of 32.
Maybe tutorial is outdated, and I need a more current instruction.

**Logs**

```
    **dmesg**
```

%%%%% EXCERPT %%%%%

```
[    0.001224] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.001381] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.001609] Mount-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.001658] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 2048 (order: 1, 8192 bytes, linear)
[    0.003267] cgroup: Disabling memory control group subsystem
[    0.003534] CPU: Testing write buffer coherency: ok
[    0.003606] CPU0: Spectre BHB: enabling loop workaround for all CPUs
[    0.004090] CPU0: thread -1, cpu 0, socket 0, mpidr 80000000
[    0.005623] Setting up static identity map for 0x200000 - 0x20003c
[    0.005846] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.006885] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.008117] CPU1: thread -1, cpu 1, socket 0, mpidr 80000001
[    0.009468] CPU2: thread -1, cpu 2, socket 0, mpidr 80000002
[    0.010848] CPU3: thread -1, cpu 3, socket 0, mpidr 80000003
[    0.011011] smp: Brought up 1 node, 4 CPUs
[    0.011091] SMP: Total of 4 processors activated (432.00 BogoMIPS).
[    0.011122] CPU: All CPU(s) started in HYP mode.
[    0.011148] CPU: Virtualization extensions available.
[    0.011967] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.027762] VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 3 part 40 variant 8 rev 0
[    0.028000] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 19112604462750000 ns
[    0.028060] futex hash table entries: 1024 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.038662] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.040088] NET: Registered PF_NETLINK/PF_ROUTE protocol family
[    0.044622] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB pool for atomic coherent allocations
[    0.045481] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.045760] audit: type=2000 audit(0.040:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.046425] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.047407] hw-breakpoint: found 5 (+1 reserved) breakpoint and 4 watchpoint registers.
[    0.047465] hw-breakpoint: maximum watchpoint size is 8 bytes.
[    0.047920] Serial: AMBA PL011 UART driver
[    0.062680] bcm2835-mbox fe00b880.mailbox: mailbox enabled
[    0.100101] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Attached to firmware from 2023-01-05T10:46:54, variant start
[    0.110118] raspberrypi-firmware soc:firmware: Firmware hash is 8ba17717fbcedd4c3b6d4bce7e50c7af4155cba9
[    0.169801] Kprobes globally optimized
[    0.176025] bcm2835-dma fe007000.dma: DMA legacy API manager, dmachans=0x1
[    0.180768] vgaarb: loaded
[    0.181304] SCSI subsystem initialized
[    0.181550] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.181641] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.181729] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.182188] usb_phy_generic phy: supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[    0.182396] usb_phy_generic phy: dummy supplies not allowed for exclusive requests
[    0.182741] pps_core: LinuxPPS API ver. 1 registered
[    0.182771] pps_core: Software ver. 5.3.6 - Copyright 2005-2007 Rodolfo Giometti <giometti@linux.it>
[    0.182820] PTP clock support registered
[    0.184537] clocksource: Switched to clocksource arch_sys_counter
[    0.265270] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.6.0
[    0.265413] VFS: Dquot-cache hash table entries: 1024 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
[    0.265618] FS-Cache: Loaded
[    0.265833] CacheFiles: Loaded
[    0.267012] simple-framebuffer 3e402000.framebuffer: framebuffer at 0x3e402000, 0x7f8000 bytes
[    0.267059] simple-framebuffer 3e402000.framebuffer: format=a8r8g8b8, mode=1920x1080x32, linelength=7680
[    0.278238] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    0.288484] simple-framebuffer 3e402000.framebuffer: fb0: simplefb registered!
[    0.297390] NET: Registered PF_INET protocol family
[    0.297718] IP idents hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.299451] tcp_listen_portaddr_hash hash table entries: 512 (order: 0, 6144 bytes, linear)
[    0.299574] Table-perturb hash table entries: 65536 (order: 6, 262144 bytes, linear)
[    0.299677] TCP established hash table entries: 8192 (order: 3, 32768 bytes, linear)
[    0.299820] TCP bind hash table entries: 8192 (order: 4, 65536 bytes, linear)
[    0.299967] TCP: Hash tables configured (established 8192 bind 8192)
[    0.300199] UDP hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.300308] UDP-Lite hash table entries: 512 (order: 2, 16384 bytes, linear)
[    0.300631] NET: Registered PF_UNIX/PF_LOCAL protocol family
[    0.301710] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    0.301796] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    0.301861] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
[    0.301926] RPC: Registered tcp NFSv4.1 backchannel transport module.
[    0.302013] PCI: CLS 0 bytes, default 64
[    1.318494] hw perfevents: enabled with armv7_cortex_a7 PMU driver, 7 counters available
[    1.341950] Initialise system trusted keyrings
[    1.342313] workingset: timestamp_bits=14 max_order=20 bucket_order=6
[    1.351439] zbud: loaded
[    1.353552] FS-Cache: Netfs 'nfs' registered for caching
[    1.354456] NFS: Registering the id_resolver key type
[    1.354588] Key type id_resolver registered
[    1.354652] Key type id_legacy registered
[    1.354833] nfs4filelayout_init: NFSv4 File Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.354920] nfs4flexfilelayout_init: NFSv4 Flexfile Layout Driver Registering...
[    1.356104] Key type asymmetric registered
[    1.356171] Asymmetric key parser 'x509' registered
[    1.356455] bounce: pool size: 64 pages
[    1.356566] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 247)
[    1.356869] io scheduler mq-deadline registered
[    1.356937] io scheduler kyber registered
[    1.369533] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: host bridge /scb/pcie@7d500000 ranges:
[    1.372619] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   No bus range found for /scb/pcie@7d500000, using [bus 00-ff]
[    1.375823] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:      MEM 0x0600000000..0x063fffffff -> 0x00c0000000
[    1.378884] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie:   IB MEM 0x0000000000..0x00ffffffff -> 0x0400000000
[    1.466642] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: link up, 5.0 GT/s PCIe x1 (SSC)
[    1.469979] brcm-pcie fd500000.pcie: PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    1.472921] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
[    1.475885] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x600000000-0x63fffffff] (bus address [0xc0000000-0xffffffff])
[    1.478886] pci 0000:00:00.0: [14e4:2711] type 01 class 0x060400
[    1.482091] pci 0000:00:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[    1.488946] PCI: bus0: Fast back to back transfers disabled
[    1.491958] pci 0000:00:00.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 00-00]), reconfiguring
[    1.495353] pci 0000:01:00.0: [1106:3483] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    1.498494] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
[    1.501979] pci 0000:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot
[    1.508831] PCI: bus1: Fast back to back transfers disabled
[    1.511795] pci_bus 0000:01: busn_res: [bus 01-ff] end is updated to 01
[    1.514861] pci 0000:00:00.0: BAR 8: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    1.517865] pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x600000000-0x600000fff 64bit]
[    1.520930] pci 0000:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    1.523921] pci 0000:00:00.0:   bridge window [mem 0x600000000-0x6000fffff]
[    1.527355] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: enabling device (0140 -> 0142)
[    1.530558] pcieport 0000:00:00.0: PME: Signaling with IRQ 77
[    1.547845] iproc-rng200 fe104000.rng: hwrng registered
[    1.551210] vc-mem: phys_addr:0x00000000 mem_base=0x3ec00000 mem_size:0x40000000(1024 MiB)
[    1.555790] gpiomem-bcm2835 fe200000.gpiomem: Initialised: Registers at 0xfe200000
[    1.571650] brd: module loaded
[    1.585139] loop: module loaded
[    1.588907] Loading iSCSI transport class v2.0-870.
[    1.597278] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: GENET 5.0 EPHY: 0x0000
[    1.694737] unimac-mdio unimac-mdio.-19: Broadcom UniMAC MDIO bus
[    1.698934] usbcore: registered new interface driver r8152
[    1.701896] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    1.704821] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.759505] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.762295] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.770697] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: hcc params 0x002841eb hci version 0x100 quirks 0x0000e40000000890
[    1.774629] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.777409] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.780240] xhci_hcd 0000:01:00.0: Host supports USB 3.0 SuperSpeed
[    1.783404] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.786279] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.789115] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.791960] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.84-v7l+ xhci-hcd
[    1.794846] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.798439] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.801317] hub 1-0:1.0: 1 port detected
[    1.805211] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.15
[    1.808027] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.810781] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.813574] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.15.84-v7l+ xhci-hcd
[    1.816397] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.819888] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.822768] hub 2-0:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    1.827722] dwc_otg: version 3.00a 10-AUG-2012 (platform bus)
[    1.830862] dwc_otg: FIQ enabled
[    1.830878] dwc_otg: NAK holdoff enabled
[    1.830893] dwc_otg: FIQ split-transaction FSM enabled
[    1.830912] Module dwc_common_port init
[    1.831393] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    1.834239] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    1.837254] mousedev: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
[    1.846040] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.848808] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
[    1.852245] sdhci-pltfm: SDHCI platform and OF driver helper
[    1.858911] ledtrig-cpu: registered to indicate activity on CPUs
[    1.861945] hid: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.864874] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.867585] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.876968] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
[    1.879777] NET: Registered PF_PACKET protocol family
[    1.882760] Key type dns_resolver registered
[    1.885934] Registering SWP/SWPB emulation handler
[    1.889439] registered taskstats version 1
[    1.892104] Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates
[    1.895601] Key type .fscrypt registered
[    1.898233] Key type fscrypt-provisioning registered
[    1.913330] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: there is not valid maps for state default
[    1.916423] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: cts_event_workaround enabled
[    1.919195] fe201000.serial: ttyAMA0 at MMIO 0xfe201000 (irq = 34, base_baud = 0) is a PL011 rev2
[    1.931317] bcm2835-wdt bcm2835-wdt: Broadcom BCM2835 watchdog timer
[    1.934587] bcm2835-power bcm2835-power: Broadcom BCM2835 power domains driver
[    1.939066] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: mmc_debug:0 mmc_debug2:0
[    1.941794] mmc-bcm2835 fe300000.mmcnr: DMA channel allocated
[    1.974686] of_cfs_init
[    1.977466] of_cfs_init: OK
[    2.018046] mmc0: SDHCI controller on fe340000.mmc [fe340000.mmc] using ADMA
[    2.021174] Waiting for root device PARTUUID=329e1073-02...
[    2.062605] mmc1: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    2.084573] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.124176] mmc0: new ultra high speed DDR50 SDHC card at address aaaa
[    2.127856] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SD32G 29.7 GiB
[    2.134192]  mmcblk0: p1 p2
[    2.137488] mmcblk0: mmc0:aaaa SD32G 29.7 GiB (quirks 0x00004000)
[    2.179796] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[    2.182638] VFS: Mounted root (ext4 filesystem) readonly on device 179:2.
[    2.190675] devtmpfs: mounted
[    2.204597] Freeing unused kernel image (initmem) memory: 2048K
[    2.207772] Run /sbin/init as init process
[    2.210514]   with arguments:
[    2.210527]     /sbin/init
[    2.210540]   with environment:
[    2.210552]     HOME=/
[    2.210566]     TERM=linux
[    2.267232] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=3431, bcdDevice= 4.21
[    2.270191] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    2.273077] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    2.278304] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    2.281378] hub 1-1:1.0: 4 ports detected
[    2.523528] systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.
[    2.731616] NET: Registered PF_INET6 protocol family
[    2.736286] Segment Routing with IPv6
[    2.739089] In-situ OAM (IOAM) with IPv6
[    2.808114] systemd[1]: systemd 247.3-7+rpi1+deb11u1 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +ZSTD +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=unified)
[    2.815298] systemd[1]: Detected architecture arm.
[    2.842867] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <strooper1>.
[    3.682640] systemd[1]: Queued start job for default target Multi-User System.
[    3.691281] systemd[1]: Created slice system-getty.slice.
[    3.699997] systemd[1]: Created slice system-modprobe.slice.
[    3.708438] systemd[1]: Created slice system-systemd\x2dfsck.slice.
[    3.716673] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[    3.724654] systemd[1]: Started Dispatch Password Requests to Console Directory Watch.
[    3.732430] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[    3.741110] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[    3.749111] systemd[1]: Reached target Local Encrypted Volumes.
[    3.757256] systemd[1]: Reached target Paths.
[    3.765211] systemd[1]: Reached target Slices.
[    3.773055] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[    3.781998] systemd[1]: Listening on Syslog Socket.
[    3.790590] systemd[1]: Listening on fsck to fsckd communication Socket.
[    3.798748] systemd[1]: Listening on initctl Compatibility Named Pipe.
[    3.807695] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Audit Socket.
[    3.816299] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket (/dev/log).
[    3.825292] systemd[1]: Listening on Journal Socket.
[    3.834957] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Control Socket.
[    3.843677] systemd[1]: Listening on udev Kernel Socket.
[    3.852567] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Huge Pages File System being skipped.
[    3.861543] systemd[1]: Mounting POSIX Message Queue File System...
[    3.875840] systemd[1]: Mounting RPC Pipe File System...
[    3.890942] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Debug File System...
[    3.905951] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Trace File System...
[    3.915119] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Kernel Module supporting RPCSEC_GSS being skipped.
[    3.926371] systemd[1]: Starting Restore / save the current clock...
[    3.941426] systemd[1]: Starting Set the console keyboard layout...
[    3.957775] systemd[1]: Starting Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel...
[    3.973944] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module configfs...
[    3.989460] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module drm...
[    4.009647] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Module fuse...
[    4.025405] systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Set Up Additional Binary Formats being skipped.
[    4.036859] systemd[1]: Starting File System Check on Root Device...
[    4.061664] systemd[1]: Starting Journal Service...
[    4.075967] fuse: init (API version 7.34)
[    4.107210] systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
[    4.135439] systemd[1]: Starting Coldplug All udev Devices...
[    4.165304] systemd[1]: Mounted POSIX Message Queue File System.
[    4.178984] systemd[1]: Mounted RPC Pipe File System.
[    4.193295] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Debug File System.
[    4.209627] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
[    4.229774] systemd[1]: Finished Restore / save the current clock.
[    4.250345] systemd[1]: Finished Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    4.271203] systemd[1]: modprobe@configfs.service: Succeeded.
[    4.276211] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module configfs.
[    4.285942] systemd[1]: modprobe@drm.service: Succeeded.
[    4.290790] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module drm.
[    4.300542] systemd[1]: modprobe@fuse.service: Succeeded.
[    4.305727] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Module fuse.
[    4.315898] systemd[1]: Finished File System Check on Root Device.
[    4.326316] systemd[1]: Finished Load Kernel Modules.
[    4.341857] systemd[1]: Mounting FUSE Control File System...
[    4.360553] systemd[1]: Mounting Kernel Configuration File System...
[    4.380250] systemd[1]: Started File System Check Daemon to report status.
[    4.397669] systemd[1]: Starting Remount Root and Kernel File Systems...
[    4.412893] systemd[1]: Starting Apply Kernel Variables...
[    4.435573] systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
[    4.465331] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.
[    4.477670] systemd[1]: Finished Set the console keyboard layout.
[    4.502401] systemd[1]: Started Journal Service.
[    4.610921] EXT4-fs (mmcblk0p2): re-mounted. Opts: (null). Quota mode: none.
[    4.681660] systemd-journald[141]: Received client request to flush runtime journal.
[    4.692709] systemd-journald[141]: File /var/log/journal/f011d957ee65457ca002260d5982b540/system.journal corrupted or uncleanly shut down, renaming and replacing.
[    6.128180] mc: Linux media interface: v0.10
[    6.163079] vc_sm_cma: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    6.165834] bcm2835_vc_sm_cma_probe: Videocore shared memory driver
[    6.165914] [vc_sm_connected_init]: start
[    6.171943] [vc_sm_connected_init]: installed successfully
[    6.280528] videodev: Linux video capture interface: v2.00
[    6.338486] brcmstb-i2c fef04500.i2c:  @97500hz registered in polling mode
[    6.339219] brcmstb-i2c fef09500.i2c:  @97500hz registered in polling mode
[    6.529831] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    6.581388] bcm2835_isp: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    6.604426] bcm2835_mmal_vchiq: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    6.611967] snd_bcm2835: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    6.644249] bcm2835_audio bcm2835_audio: card created with 8 channels
[    6.686973] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node output[0] registered as /dev/video13
[    6.693067] bcm2835_codec: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    6.695261] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[0] registered as /dev/video14
[    6.698458] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[1] registered as /dev/video15
[    6.699147] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node stats[2] registered as /dev/video16
[    6.699182] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register output node 0 with media controller
[    6.699206] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 1 with media controller
[    6.699230] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 2 with media controller
[    6.699254] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 3 with media controller
[    6.725097] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node output[0] registered as /dev/video20
[    6.725753] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[0] registered as /dev/video21
[    6.726279] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node capture[1] registered as /dev/video22
[    6.726661] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Device node stats[2] registered as /dev/video23
[    6.726696] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register output node 0 with media controller
[    6.726731] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 1 with media controller
[    6.726764] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 2 with media controller
[    6.726803] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Register capture node 3 with media controller
[    6.727074] bcm2835-isp bcm2835-isp: Loaded V4L2 bcm2835-isp
[    6.763431] rpivid_hevc: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    6.793566] [drm] Initialized v3d 1.0.0 20180419 for fec00000.v3d on minor 0
[    6.846517] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video10
[    6.846575] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 decode
[    6.860831] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video11
[    6.860886] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode
[    6.868161] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video12
[    6.868215] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 isp
[    6.871560] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video18
[    6.871617] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 image_fx
[    6.877234] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Device registered as /dev/video31
[    6.877293] bcm2835-codec bcm2835-codec: Loaded V4L2 encode_image
[    6.907727] rpivid feb10000.codec: Device registered as /dev/video19
[    6.929864] bcm2835_v4l2: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    7.055771] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    7.121098] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    7.130501] cfg80211: loaded regulatory.db is malformed or signature is missing/invalid
[    7.483314] brcmfmac: F1 signature read @0x18000000=0x15264345
[    7.495675] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[    7.532853] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
[    7.778423] brcmfmac: brcmf_fw_alloc_request: using brcm/brcmfmac43455-sdio for chip BCM4345/6
[    7.784508] brcmfmac: brcmf_c_preinit_dcmds: Firmware: BCM4345/6 wl0: Nov  1 2021 00:37:25 version 7.45.241 (1a2f2fa CY) FWID 01-703fd60
[    8.386403] checking generic (3e402000 7f8000) vs hw (0 ffffffffffffffff)
[    8.386440] fb0: switching to vc4 from simple
[    8.387244] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x30
[    8.426792] vc4-drm gpu: bound fe400000.hvs (ops vc4_hvs_ops [vc4])
[    8.451985] Registered IR keymap rc-cec
[    8.452214] rc rc0: vc4 as /devices/platform/soc/fef00700.hdmi/rc/rc0
[    8.452544] input: vc4 as /devices/platform/soc/fef00700.hdmi/rc/rc0/input0
[    8.489180] vc4-drm gpu: bound fef00700.hdmi (ops vc4_hdmi_ops [vc4])
[    8.493083] Registered IR keymap rc-cec
[    8.503549] rc rc1: vc4 as /devices/platform/soc/fef05700.hdmi/rc/rc1
[    8.504180] input: vc4 as /devices/platform/soc/fef05700.hdmi/rc/rc1/input1
[    8.612976] vc4-drm gpu: bound fef05700.hdmi (ops vc4_hdmi_ops [vc4])
[    8.614177] vc4-drm gpu: bound fe004000.txp (ops vc4_txp_ops [vc4])
[    8.616319] vc4-drm gpu: bound fe206000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[    8.616853] vc4-drm gpu: bound fe207000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[    8.617339] vc4-drm gpu: bound fe20a000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[    8.617775] vc4-drm gpu: bound fe216000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[    8.618305] vc4-drm gpu: bound fec12000.pixelvalve (ops vc4_crtc_ops [vc4])
[    8.632089] uart-pl011 fe201000.serial: no DMA platform data
[    8.635836] hwmon hwmon1: Undervoltage detected!
[    8.645939] [drm] Initialized vc4 0.0.0 20140616 for gpu on minor 1
[    8.833618] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    8.861247] vc4-drm gpu: [drm] fb0: vc4drmfb frame buffer device
[    9.279811] 8021q: 802.1Q VLAN Support v1.8
[    9.560960] brcmfmac: brcmf_cfg80211_set_power_mgmt: power save enabled
[    9.790343] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet: configuring instance for external RGMII (RX delay)
[    9.791536] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Down
[   10.714572] hwmon hwmon1: Voltage normalised
[   15.818354] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   16.337632] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[   16.337704] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[   16.337710] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.337727] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.337735] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.337751] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   16.345680] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[   16.345691] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[   16.345749] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[   16.345890] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[   16.601860] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   16.601871] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   16.601883] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   16.620532] NET: Registered PF_ALG protocol family
[   16.636911] cryptd: max_cpu_qlen set to 1000
[   17.053253] ICMPv6: process `dhcpcd' is using deprecated sysctl (syscall) net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time - use net.ipv6.neigh.wlan0.retrans_time_ms instead
[   24.314791] bcmgenet fd580000.ethernet eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   24.314856] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
**[   32.474616] cam-dummy-reg: disabling**
```

Comment: `Maybe should of went with 64bit OS` did you try? `Maybe tutorial is outdated` which tutorial? `dmesg` pretty, but what are you trying to show with that? `cam-dummy-reg: disabling` is NOT an error

Comment: ANY tutorial which recommends `sudo rpi-update` is suspect. "You should not use rpi-update on any system unless recommended to do so by a Raspberry Pi engineer. It may leave your system unreliable or even completely broken. It should not be used as part of any regular update process."
https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/os.html#rpi-update

Comment: Is this an assignment for a class you're taking? It sounds like it is. It also sounds (to me anyway) like you've not put enough effort into this to phrase it as a decent question. I'd recommend you delete this & start over.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.com/tutorials/cluster-raspberry-pi-tutorial/
Not a school course. Self-learning.
No have not tried, 64 bit. I have put so much time an energy into this. I would be nice to get some suggestion on what do about this block I am facing. Worker node will not boot beyond that point.. 
Are there any other logs which would be helpful to see?
Is this install issue resolvable?
If not, can you recommend a more reliable/current instruction?